# Shell script: Simple parameter comparison doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Musikscript für Android-App
#sudo killall -9 mplayer
#sudo  mplayer -ao alsa:device=hw=0.0 -playlist /home/pi/media/radio/ANTENNE-BAYERN.m3u   &
echo $1
echo $2

if [ "$1" = "playlist" ]
then
    sudo mplayer -ao alsa:device=hw=0.0 -playlist $2 &
fi

if [ "$1" = "playfile" ]
then
    sudo mplayer -ao alsa:device=hw=0.0 $2 &
fi

if [ "&1" = "stop" ]
then
    sudo killall -9 mplayer
fi

if [ "$1" = "volume" ]
then
    sudo amixer set PCM $2
fi
```

When I try to run a file with:

```
sudo sh /home/pi/scripts/mplayerscript.sh "playlist" "/home/pi/media/radio/ANTENNE-BAYERN.m3u"
```

It works without a problem, but

```
sudo sh /home/pi/scripts/mplayerscript.sh "stop"
```

only executes the 2 echo lines.

Comment: Well, take a closer look the comparison with `"stop"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"&1" = "stop"`.. I think you meant `"$1" = "stop"` :)

Comment: Shame on me :D I read it for like 100x and didn't notice. Thank you very much ^^

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I think you meant $1 instead of &1.

But when you have a script like that, conditions based on only one parameter, like $1 in your script, it's way easier to use "case".

case "$1" in

"playlist")

```
  sudo mplayer -ao alsa:device=hw=0.0 -playlist $2 &
 ;;
```

"playfile")

```
 sudo mplay -ao alsa:device=hw=0.0 $2 &
 ;;
```

"stop")

```
 sudo killall -9 mplayer
 ;;
```

"volume")

```
 sudo amixer set PCM $2
 ;;
```

esac